# Shopify liquid product.thumbnail.liquid repeats block even there is no loops

Tags: loops, shopify, liquid

[![enter image description here][1]][1]My job Is too simple i.e just to add Amazon url in a div block in product thumbnail.liquid.I Have added just simple div, then I found that same div is repeated twice. I have also checked that there is no `forloop` found still how does it is repeating .Today I found the file called `product-loop.liquid` which has `for` loop and `product thumbnail.liquid` is included. What I need to do if I need to show amazon link block only once? Entire file is in gist link.Thanks.

product-loop.liquid

```
{% assign product_found = false %}
{% assign skip = false %}
{% assign collection_group = products | map: 'id' %}
{% assign collection_group_thumb = collection_group | append : 'thumb' %}
{% assign collection_group_mobile = collection_group | append : 'mobile' %}

{% capture new_row %}
    <br class="clear product_clear" />
{% endcapture %}

<div itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList" class="products">
  {% for product in products limit: limit %}
    {% if product.id == skip_product.id or skip == true %}
      {% assign product_found = true %}
    {% else %}
      {% if forloop.rindex0 == 0 and product_found == false and forloop.length != products.count and template != 'search' %}
        {% assign skip = true %}
      {% else %}

        {% include 'product-thumbnail', sidebar: sidebar %}

        {% if products_per_row == 2 %}
          {% cycle collection_group: '', new_row %}
        {% elsif products_per_row == 3 %}
          {% cycle collection_group: '', '', new_row %}    
        {% elsif products_per_row == 4 %}  
          {% cycle collection_group: '', '', '', new_row %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}    
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: you can check you include product-thumbnail inside a for loop thats why it is repeating.....hope you got it solution

Comment: sorry , I don't got solution how to show link only once I am new to this liquid language.could you guide me ?

Comment: you can understand how can i help you with here if you share details with me so i can cross check for you and give you solution

Comment: sure. How do I connect you ? What details you required?

Comment: can you please create a staff account for me on your system so i can login on store

Comment: can I give you Teamviewer access ? Since I don't have access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172502/discussion-between-amar-ghodke-and-niraj-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you including product.thumbnail in a section and that section have loop or conditional logics.

Comment: How to inspect it ?

Comment: check your theme code where you include product.thumbnail